# Generic constraint on T to be reference type and value type simultaneously?

Tags: c#, constraints, generics, value-type, reference-type

I have a problem with understanding how generic constraints work. I think I am missing something important here. I have enclosed my questions in the comments and would be grateful for providing some explanation.

```
//1st example:

class C <T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : struct, T
{
}
//Above code compiles well, 
//On first sight it looks like U might be reference type and value type
//at the same time. The only reason I can think of, is that T may be an 
//interface which struct can implement, Am I correct?

//2nd example

class CC<T, U>
    where T : class, new ()
    where U : struct, T
{
}

//I added also a reguirement for parameterless constructor
//and, much to my surprise, it still compiles what is
//a bit inexplicable for me.
//What 'U' would meet the requirement to be 
//value type, reference type and have a contructor at the same time?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that. Let's look at the definition of the [constraints on the type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx):

- `T : class` - The type argument T must be a reference type, including any class, interface, delegate, or array type.
- `U : struct` - The type argument U must be a value type.
- `U : T`  - The type argument U must be or derive from the class T.

So all you need to do is find a value type that derives from a reference type. At first that might sound impossible, but if you think a bit harder you will remember that all structs derive from the class `object`, so this works fine for both your examples:

```
new C<object, int>();
```

However if you swap `struct` and `class` then it won't compile:

```
// Error - Type parameter 'T' has the 'struct' constraint so 'T'
//         cannot be used as a constraint for 'U'
class C<T, U>
    where T : struct
    where U : class, T
{
}
```

Comment: Yes? and ? You specified it for the T, which would match the object constructor. That's OK.

Comment: Yes you're right, I read it wrong. @Mark Byers you said that all structs derive from `object`. SO If I had `class CS<T> where T : class{}` Code like `CS<DateTime> obj = new CS<DateTime>();` wouldn't work whereas `DateTime` is castable to object.

Comment: @Andrzej Nosal: Yes, because the constraint `T : class` doesn't mean *T is castable to object*. It means *T must be a reference type*. DateTime is not a reference type.

Comment: `C<Enum, someEnumeratedType>` is valid as well ;)

Comment: @Hans Passant: +1 Good point - and perhaps surprisingly the type `ValueType` is a reference type so `C<ValueType, int>` works too. :)